# How to fix faces "overlapping" and "alignment" when moving bones?

Tags: rigging

I'm playing with blender just for learning, having fun with it so far, I'm just a beginner. I've a model and I'm trying to link a bone to it so I can animate. It does work but there are two problems.

Turns out this nice dude is wearing a skirt but he's a man don't worry, when I move his feets the legs are overlapping the skirt.

[image]

The second problem is, when I move a foot it is not keeping aligned with the leg

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1EFLAMi.png]

So, could someone tell me how can I fix those problems? Thank you in advance.
Here's the blend file by the way: https://drive.google.com/file/d/102QRhkBZU40U7gwZHgP2IpDYwkDNkrmG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you did not weight painting the pants yet ,

That's why the thigh is overlapping the pants because the pants area does not assigned with the thigh bone, so it does not follow along with the thigh bone.

You need to weight painting the pants so the pants will follow along with the thigh.

IF you do not understand what is Weight Painting maybe you can check this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl4qTgwQwYw

[image]

And also the main problem is the topology of the character is messed up, with lots of triangles and NGONs. You will get lots of problems when animating. You need to clean the topology or retopology before you can animate it. You cannot animate this character with this kind of that topology.

With this kind of topology, it is impossible to be animated.

You can learn what is Topology and why you need it from Grant Arbitt. He has very good tips for beginners with good explanations.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4YNiImIgPs

[image]

For Example :

1.Your foot is not aligned with the leg part, It happens because you separate the foot object with the body. In general, human body is all connected nothing separated. This is also some kind of bad topology for character animation.

2. Same with your shoulder hand, below picture, this because the hand part and the body is separated.

There are so many problems here that I cant write it all here. You can just watch the link that I gave above. It will explain a lot what caused these problems.

[image]

At last, This is caused because of the bad topology and rigging (weight painting). If you are beginner in Blender, I recommend you to learn the basic / fundamental concept before doing complex things. By doing that, you can follow along easily and achieve anything from Blender in the future.

Comment: Hey thanks for the explanation, seems like getting a few basic models for my piece of a game is not going to be an easy task lol, I will definitely get depth into blender. I've tried to paint the weights as you suggested and it was indeed the problem, at least one part of it, but that was before I saw the update you made to your answer. Although I couldn't get the model to work properly I'll mark your answer as the solution, as it was very helpful

Comment: Yep, unfortunately you can not animate this model properly as your topology model is so messed up. No one can animate that model. 

The only solution is you need to clean the topology. You can just search in google "Human Topology".